# c# / wpf: UI not responsive at start

Tags: c#, user-interface, task

We have a frond-end app with lots of 3rd party dlls, some offering a variety of wpf controls. In our scenario, the user clicks a treeview item and a belonging view is created. 
Problem: The UI freezes, lots of dlls get loaded (as displayed in the debugger output) and it takes a lot time (8-9 sec) seeing the clicked treeview item selected.
I know that .net loads dlls on demand, and it's ok. There should be no delayed dll loading experiments.
Instead I think of making single UI componentse e.g. the TreeView responsive, that it shows the selected item immediately, and showing a progress just as long dlls get loaded. I have no great experience in .Net Task programming yet.
What do you think ? Is it worth an approach ?

Comment: Yes. However you will have problems with this if the DLLs are accessing the UI or its components directly. If the DLLs are merely crunching, then is definitely a case where you can use threading.

Comment: Move your code for creating the view into a background worker and run it asynchronously.  Your UI will remain respoinsive and you can put in a progress bar if you like.

Comment: Be aware that the delay-loading of dlls is especially expensive in the debugger (because the debugger is also loading the debug info at that point). The impact may be a lot smaller when you run the application in release mode and without the debugger.

Comment: As @PMF already pointed out with a Debugger attached it can be alot slower, also check your Debugging Settings in General, there are some that slow down this reference loading even more.